# tomcat 8.5.43 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException

Tags: jsp, compilation, runtime-error, tomcat8.5, classformatexception

I have been using tomcat 8.5.43 which ships with ecj 4.6.3 jar. I am still getting the following issue.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | An error occurred at line: [36] in the jsp file: [/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common/footer/footer.tag]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.contents.components.AbstractCMSComponentModel cannot be resolved to a type
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 33: </div>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 34: </c:if>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 35: <cms:pageSlot position="Footer" var="feature" element="div" class="footer">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 36: <cms:component component="${feature}"/>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 37: </cms:pageSlot>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | Stacktrace:] with root cause
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | An error occurred at line: [1] in the generated java file: [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.43/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/tag/web/desktop/common/footer/footer_tag.java]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | The type de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.contents.contentslot.ContentSlotModel cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | An error occurred at line: [1] in the generated java file: [/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.43/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/org/apache/jsp/tag/web/desktop/common/footer/footer_tag.java]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | The type de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.contents.components.AbstractCMSComponentModel cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | An error occurred at line: [13] in the jsp file: [/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common/footer/footer.tag]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | The method setContentSlot(ContentSlotModel) from the type CMSContentSlotTag refers to the missing type ContentSlotModel
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 10: <div id="footer_logo"></div>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 11: <div id="footer_panel_bar">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 12: <div id="footer_left">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 13: <cms:slot contentSlot="${slots.FooterTopNavigation}" var="feature">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 14: <c:if test='${(feature.uid ne "downloadFooterLinkComponent") || accessDownloadCatalog}'>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 15: <cms:component component="${feature}" />
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 16: <script>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | An error occurred at line: [13] in the jsp file: [/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common/footer/footer.tag]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.contents.contentslot.ContentSlotModel cannot be resolved to a type
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 10: <div id="footer_logo"></div>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 11: <div id="footer_panel_bar">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 12: <div id="footer_left">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.172 | 13: <cms:slot contentSlot="${slots.FooterTopNavigation}" var="feature">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 14: <c:if test='${(feature.uid ne "downloadFooterLinkComponent") || accessDownloadCatalog}'>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 15: <cms:component component="${feature}" />
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 16: <script>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | An error occurred at line: [13] in the jsp file: [/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common/footer/footer.tag]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | de.hybris.platform.cms2.model.contents.contentslot.ContentSlotModel cannot be resolved to a type
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 10: <div id="footer_logo"></div>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 11: <div id="footer_panel_bar">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 12: <div id="footer_left">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 13: <cms:slot contentSlot="${slots.FooterTopNavigation}" var="feature">
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 14: <c:if test='${(feature.uid ne "downloadFooterLinkComponent") || accessDownloadCatalog}'>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 15: <cms:component component="${feature}" />
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 16: <script>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2021/07/07 01:51:20.174 | An error occurred at line: [15] in the jsp file: [/WEB-INF/tags/desktop/common/footer/footer.tag]
```

- I have tried by changing the ecj jar to 4.5.1.
- removed the tomcat 'work' directory.
  But no luck, please advise !

Comment: Can you add the whole stack trace (_Caused by_ included) and the JSP which fails to compile? You are probably using the latest JDK to compile your application, while Jasper uses an old compiler (`ecj-4.6.3.jar` is ECJ version 3.12.3). Try with the [latest ecj release](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jdt/ecj/3.26.0).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I don't see a "Caused By" section is the log. Added the "with root cause" section and updated the above log.

Comment: You seem to be missing a library. Since the class seems to be part of proprietary SAP software, it is hard to tell which one.